# Alternative algorithm for integral calculation inaccurate

Tags: c++, algorithm, integral

I thought of an algorithm for integral calculation that should be more accurate that the regular rectangle approach. My algorithm can be best described with a graphic (I am using f(x) = sin(x) as example): 
[image: algorithm]

1. First the x and y positions of the points P1, P2, P3, P4 are
   calculated (red dots).
2. The area of the green four sided figure is a part of the result.
   This area is calculated by dividing it into two triangles (blue
   line).
3. The area of each triangle is calculated using the Heron’s formula.

I think it is obvious that this should lead to much better results than the rectangle approach.

In code this looks like this:

```
double integral(double f(double x), double min, double max) {
    Point p1, p2, p3, p4;
    double area = 0.0;
    double s1 = 0.0;
    double s2 = 0.0;


    for(double x = min; x < max; x += stepSize) {
        p1.x = x;
        p1.y = 0.0;

        p2.x = x;
        p2.y = f(x);

        p3.x = x + stepSize;
        p3.y = f(x + stepSize);

        p4.x = x + stepSize;
        p4.y = 0.0;


        s1 = 0.5 * (distance(p1, p2) + distance(p2, p4) + distance(p1, p4));
        s2 = 0.5 * (distance(p2, p3) + distance(p3, p4) + distance(p2, p4));

        area += sqrt(s1 * (s1 - distance(p1, p2)) * (s1 - distance(p2, p4)) * (s1 - distance(p1, p4)));
        area += sqrt(s2 * (s2 - distance(p2, p3)) * (s2 - distance(p3, p4)) * (s2 - distance(p2, p4)));
    }

    return area;
}
```

The `distance` function is just returning the distance between two points in 2D space. The `Point` struct is just holding a x and y coordinate. `stepSize` is a constant that I set to `0.001`

My function is giving a result that is correct, but I wanted to know how much more precise it is compared to the rectangle approach.

On the internet I found this code that is calculating a integral using rectangles:

```
double integral2(double(*f)(double x), double a, double b, int n) {
    double step = (b - a) / n;  // width of each small rectangle
    double area = 0.0;  // signed area
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++) {
        area += f(a + (i + 0.5) * step) * step; // sum up each small rectangle
    }
    return area;
}
```

I both tested them using the standard `math.h` `sin` function from 0.0 to half π. This area should be 1.

My algorithm has given me the result `1.000204` for a step-size of `0.001`.

The rectangle algorithm hast given me the result `1.000010` with a calculated step-size of `0.015708`.

**How can such a difference in accuracy and step-size be explained?** 
Did I implement my algorithm wrong?

**Update**

Using the calculated step-size of the second method, I get the result `0.999983` which is much closer to one than the result with a step-size of `0.001`.

Now how can that work??

Comment: Standard floating point rounding issues? See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) for details

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I made sure all functions are using doubles only

Comment: `double` is still a floating point type, and as such will have rounding errors even if they will be smaller than for `float`. The more operations you do with your floating point values, the bigger the error will get (the rounding compounds).

Comment: I would have computed the area of the trapezoids without dividing them into triangles. This will reduce the number of floating point operations and with them (hopfully) the rounding error.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes obviously, but the other function is calculating with much more accuracy with a smaller step-size.

Comment: @Johan that's a good idea, but I think this shouldn't explain this inaccuracy

Comment: you are using a first order method compared to zero oder rectangles. The main difference is that rectagles approximate the function with piecewise constant functions (0-th order) while you approximate the function with piecewise linear functions (1st odrder). Making the dx small enough they will both converge to the same result, but yours will converge faster

Comment: note that this isnt a spectacular discovery (I dont want to belittle your approach, it is a nice one!), but it is a well known fact that you can take this further by approximating the orgininal function with polynomials to get even faster convergence

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 could you please explain that in an easier language?

Comment: i added this question to my favourites and hope i can find time to write an easy to understand answer, just dont have the time now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last trapezoid may be too wide: `x+stepSize` may be above `max` if `max-min` isn't a multiple of `stepSize`. That's why in the rectangular summation code you included, rather than `stepSize`, they use `n` (the number of rectangles).

You compute the trapezoid in a complicated way. Note that its area is `stepSize * (P2.y + P3.y)/2`. This adds computation cost, but I guess is not the cause of the numerical error in your test integral.

Except for these issues, your method is otherwise equivalent to the trapezoid rule. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule

Here is Python code that approximates the integral in three different ways, using 100 rectangles. The three ways are `trap_heron` (your method, using Heron's rule), `trap` (trapezoid method), and `rect` (rectangular summation). Your question is C++, but the results should be the same.

```
import math

N = 100

def dist(a, b):
    dx = a[0] - b[0]
    dy = a[1] - b[1]
    return math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)

def trap_heron(f, min, max):
    area = 0.0
    for i in range(N):
        x0 = min + (max-min) * i/N
        x1 = min + (max-min) * (i+1)/N
        y0 = f(x0)
        y1 = f(x1)

        p1 = (x0, 0.0)
        p2 = (x0, y0)
        p3 = (x1, y1)
        p4 = (x1, 0.0)

        s1 = 0.5 * (dist(p1, p2) + dist(p2, p4) + dist(p1, p4))
        s2 = 0.5 * (dist(p2, p3) + dist(p3, p4) + dist(p2, p4))

        area += math.sqrt(s1 * (s1 - dist(p1, p2)) * (s1 - dist(p2, p4)) * (s1 - dist(p1, p4)))
        area += math.sqrt(s2 * (s2 - dist(p2, p3)) * (s2 - dist(p3, p4)) * (s2 - dist(p2, p4)))
    return area

def trap(f, min, max):
    area = 0.0
    for i in range(N):
        x0 = min + (max-min) * i/N
        x1 = min + (max-min) * (i+1)/N
        y0 = f(x0)
        y1 = f(x1)
        area += (x1-x0) * (y0+y1)/2

    return area


def rect(f, min, max):
    area = 0.0
    for i in range(N):
        y = f(min + (max-min)*(i+0.5)/N)
        area += (max-min)/N * y
    return area

print(trap(math.sin, 0, math.pi/2))
print(trap_heron(math.sin, 0, math.pi/2))
print(rect(math.sin, 0, math.pi/2))
```

The output is:

```
0.9999794382396076
0.9999794382396054
1.0000102809119051
```

Note that `trap` and `trap_heron` produce very nearly the same result.

In your comments, you have a result of 1.015686. The error is very close to stepSize * sin(pi/2), so I guess you've summed up one too many trapezoids.

Comment: Interesting idea, I now am setting step-size to be `(max - min) / rectangles`. But with 100 rectangles in both methods my new results are `1.015686` with my method and `1.000010` with the rectangles. How does this work?

Comment: Thanks, that one extra trapezoid was the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can try Kahan summation to reduce the error but the precision issue is real. You are approximating the integral using a numerical method after all.

Comment: What does numerical method mean? I haven't learned about integrals in school yet.

Comment: @user11914177 Simplified, simply see "numerical methods" as opposed to "analytically absolute correct methods". Essentially, it is a field of math that deals with approximating things rather than calculating them (while being able to quantify how close one is to the actual solution).